# LiveCode Repeat

Tags: repeat, livecode

I am trying to use repeat to display the "Species" node of each of the "XmlNode"s. However, I keep getting an error. I am a new to LiveCode and have tried everything I can think of.

XML CODE:

```
<ArrayOfXmlNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.petango.com/">
  <XmlNode>
    <adoptableSearch xmlns="">
      <ID>12063964</ID>
      <Name>152217</Name>
      <Species>Dog</Species>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <PrimaryBreed>Doberman Pinscher</PrimaryBreed>
      <SecondaryBreed>Mix</SecondaryBreed>
      <SN>Neutered</SN>
      <Age>70</Age>
      <Photo>
        http://www.petango.com/sms/photos/119/6cd81b69-357c-4272-b064-    d3fb3038985e_TN1.jpg
      </Photo>
      <Location>Adoption</Location>
      <OnHold>No</OnHold>
      <SpecialNeeds></SpecialNeeds>
      <NoDogs></NoDogs>
      <NoCats></NoCats>
      <NoKids></NoKids>
      <BehaviorResult></BehaviorResult>
      <MemoList/>
      <ARN></ARN>
      <BehaviorTestList></BehaviorTestList>
      <Stage>Available</Stage>
      <AnimalType>Dog</AnimalType>
      <AgeGroup>Adult</AgeGroup>
      <WildlifeIntakeInjury></WildlifeIntakeInjury>
      <WildlifeIntakeCause></WildlifeIntakeCause>
      <BuddyID>0</BuddyID>
      <Featured>No</Featured>
      <Sublocation>K27</Sublocation>
      <ChipNumber>0A12047D2B</ChipNumber>
    </adoptableSearch>
  </XmlNode>
  <XmlNode>
    <adoptableSearch xmlns="">
      <ID>13423810</ID>
      <Name>145957</Name>
      <Species>Dog</Species>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <PrimaryBreed>Chihuahua, Short Coat</PrimaryBreed>
      <SecondaryBreed>Mix</SecondaryBreed>
      <SN>Neutered</SN>
      <Age>99</Age>
      <Photo>
        http://www.petango.com/sms/photos/119/5839bd2b-f15e-4e40-b5e1-9a20331de212_TN1.jpg
      </Photo>
      <Location>Stray Room</Location>
      <OnHold>No</OnHold>
      <SpecialNeeds></SpecialNeeds>
      <NoDogs></NoDogs>
      <NoCats></NoCats>
      <NoKids></NoKids>
      <BehaviorResult></BehaviorResult>
      <MemoList/>
      <ARN></ARN>
      <BehaviorTestList></BehaviorTestList>
      <Stage>72 hour hold</Stage>
      <AnimalType>Dog</AnimalType>
      <AgeGroup>Baby</AgeGroup>
      <WildlifeIntakeInjury></WildlifeIntakeInjury>
      <WildlifeIntakeCause></WildlifeIntakeCause>
      <BuddyID>0</BuddyID>
      <Featured>No</Featured>
      <Sublocation>Stray Room 8</Sublocation>
      <ChipNumber>0A123F1156</ChipNumber>
    </adoptableSearch>
  </XmlNode>
```

LIVECODE CODE:

```
on mouseUp
 put url "http://www.petango.com/webservices/wsadoption.asmx/AdoptableSearch?authkey=XXXXXX&speciesID=&sex=&ageGroup=&location=&site=&onHold=&orderBy=&primaryBreed=&secondaryBreed=&specialNeeds=&noDogs=&noCats=&noKids=&stageID=" into  tURL
 put revCreateXMLTree( tURL, true, true, false) into tInfo

 put revXMLChildNames( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode", return, , true) into tChildren
 repeat for each line tChild in tChildren      
  put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/" & tChild & "/Species") &    
  return after tSpecies
 end repeat 

 put tSpecies
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following which includes `adoptableSearch` in the node path:

```
on mouseUp
 put url "http://www.petango.com/webservices/wsadoption.asmx/AdoptableSearch?authkey=XXXXXX&speciesID=&sex=&ageGroup=&location=&site=&onHold=&orderBy=&primaryBreed=&secondaryBreed=&specialNeeds=&noDogs=&noCats=&noKids=&stageID=" into  tURL
 put revCreateXMLTree( tURL, true, true, false) into tInfo

 put revXMLChildNames( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode", return, , true) into tChildren
 repeat for each line tChild in tChildren      
  put revXMLNodeContents( tInfo, "ArrayOfXmlNode/" & tChild & "/adoptableSearch/Species") &    
  return after tSpecies
 end repeat 

 put tSpecies
end mouseUp
```